# am trying to use the node js terminal, please what does the error say?

Tags: node.js

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\source\app'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
PS C:\source>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023672/how-do-i-resolve-cannot-find-module-error-using-node-js

Comment: Can you please show your code and directorys

Comment: "Cannot find module" - the error is clear to me. What are you running?

Comment: Am running a javascript file "app.js" saved on the C drive.